# How to set a scatter chart legend in VBA?

Tags: vba, charts

It seems to be a simple problem, but I cannot find a solution anywhere. I have a scatter chart created from two columns of data in Excel by a VBA macro. There are 500 points (pairs of XY values), 200 of which have green color, the rest are blue. The chart is perfect and has everything except the legend. I want to add a very simple legend on the  top of the chart, below the title, showing something like this: blue dot -- "data N1" and green dot -- "data N2".

How to do it?

Answer (score 1):

How are the points colored differently? If you use two series of X and Y values, each series will have its own formatting and series name, both of which are displayed in the legend. One of the default legend positions is "top", which means between the chart and the chart title.

Answer (score 0):

That's not really how scatterplots work. Without seeing your worksheet, I suspect that what you have is *one* series of data (two columns, so that would be your X/Y pairs).  No matter what colors you apply to the points, Excel still interprets this as *one series* of data, so you will only ever get one legend entry.

Add a second series, and you'll get a second legend entry.

[image]